# Foreach inside a form select

Tags: php, forms, foreach, html-select

I want that the user can select 1 of the ranks, My code

```
$sqlUitlezenRanksUitlezen = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `Ranks` ORDER BY `RankID`");
//$sqlDataRanksUitlezen = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlUitlezenAccountBewerken);
foreach($sqlUitlezenRanksUitlezen AS $sqlUitlezenRanksUitlezenEach) {
    echo '<option value="'.$sqlUitlezenRankEach['RankID'].'">'.$sqlUitlezenRankEach['RankNaam'].'</option>';
}
```

But if i do this, it will not display the rank name. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: You never fetch your results. Any basic mysql tutorial will cover this.

Comment: How do i fetch my results?

Comment: Oh i see it now, My value is not correct

Comment: Dude seriously?@JohnConde explained you!Go watch some basic tutorials...

Comment: Take out the `//` and you will be fetching. That's a comment as is, or is that just how it formatted here?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:-**

```
$sqlUitlezenRanksUitlezen = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `Ranks` ORDER BY    `RankID`");
    $sqlDataRanksUitlezen = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlUitlezenAccountBewerken);
    foreach($sqlDataRanksUitlezen AS $sqlUitlezenRanksUitlezenEach) {
        echo '<option value="'.$sqlUitlezenRankEach['RankID'].'">'.$sqlUitlezenRankEach['RankNaam'].'</option>';
    }
```